# Google Analytics iOS app showing different data (61% different)

Tags: google-analytics

A while back I installed the Google Analytics app for iOS, this one ==> https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/id881599038?mt=8

I noticed that it showed a different number of Unique Visitors compared to total number of Users in the web-interface of Google Analytics at google.com/analytics

The difference is 61%... the app shows 61% **MORE** Unique visitors compared to the web version of Google Analytics.

How is this different? Or why?

Am I the only one experiencing this?

Comment: Seems that you are not the only one: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56519/google-analytics-web-data-vastly-different-than-the-core-reporting-api-data?rq=1

Comment: I am seeing this too, on the Android app, and in my case the uniques on the web are higher by ~30/40% to those on the app - when running for last 30 days.